# Add class to link in wp_list_pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a hover-effect on a list-item within the `wp_list_pages()` function. I'm creating a theme for Wordpress, but can't seem to get the hover effect working. I'm pretty new at this, so bear with me.

My css looks like this:

```
a.nav:hover { color: yellow; }
```

So for my html-code I add the "nav"-class to my links, like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a class="nav" href="#">HOME</a></li>
</ul>
```

This works, it changes the color of the link to yellow. So far so good. 
But when I try to change this html-code to  php-code the class isn't there.

I use the `wp_list_pages()` function, like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
<?PHP wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1&sort_column=menu_order&exclude='); ?>
</ul>
```

And the outcome then is:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="http://example.com/blog/page_id=23">HOME</a></li></ul>
```

So my question is, how to I add the `nav` class to this link? Is there an attribute within the function or something? Again, I'm really new to this

Comment: Both the `ul` and `a` have the class `nav` that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the wordpress docs for `wp_list_pages()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#Markup_and_styling_of_page_items :

> ll list items (li) generated by wp_list_pages() are marked with the class page_item. When wp_list_pages() is called while displaying a Page, the list item for that Page is given the additional class current_page_item.

with that, the easiest thing you can do is to just change your hover code to:

```
li.page_item:hover { color: yellow; }
```

Comment: Actually, I've done that already. You see, my list-items are blocks, 100x100px, and the color changes from black to yellow. The thing is, my links are inside the block, and I want the text to change color as well, from white to black. Anyway, thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: @HåvardBrynjulfsen in that case, just select `li.page_item:hover a { /* change link's color here */ }`

Comment: Been stuck at this for hours, thank you very much! It worked! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-classes-to-wp_list_pages).

Quote: "Add the following line to your theme's functions.php template file, and it will add a class attribute of "tag" to each link generated by wp_list_pages():

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', create_function('$t', 'return str_replace("<a ", "<a class=\"tag\" ", $t);'));
```

Comment: For those looking for solutions to to this, it turns out `create_function` is [deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). For people using PHP >= 5.3.0, the same docs recommend an anonymous function instead.

Comment: It is not necessary to make it an inline function. You might as well create a regular function, with a name like add_class_to_wp_list_pages, and call it like add_filter( 'wp_list_pages', 'add_class_to_wp_list_pages' );

Answer (score 2):

I think that the proper way change the default class of a wp_list_pages function is this:

```
// add to functions.php

// add classes to wp_list_pages
function wp_list_pages_filter($output) {
  $output = str_replace('page_item', 'page_item new-class', $output);
  return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'wp_list_pages_filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

What if I have a different looks on each pages then I have to call only a specific class. The example below is the best way that worked for me.

`page.index`:

```
<aside class="menu-side">
      <ul class="side-nav-list">
        <li>
            <!-- First child ( title of the page) -->
          <a  href="#"><?php the_title() ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php 
          if($theParent){
            $findChildOf = $theParent;
          }else{
            $findChildOf = get_the_ID();
          }
        
          wp_list_pages(array(
            'title_li' => NULL,
            'child_of' => $findChildOf,
          ))
        ?>
      </ul>
    </aside>
```

CSS file:

```
.side-nav-list li a:link,
.side-nav-list li a:visited {

         display: block;
         padding: 1.6rem 1.2rem;
         color: #2d234b;}
```